# Does python execute imports on importation

Tags: python, python-import

Lets say I have a module named `module1` with the following:

```
def main():
    print 'K DawG'

main()
```

and a `module2` with only this line:

```
import module1
```

What basically happens is, when I run `module1` it **does** print `K DawG` as expected and when I run `moudle2`, unless I explicitly state `module1.main()` It **shouldn't** do anything but it too prints `K DawG`

Why is this so? Does python run the scripts imported during their importation? If so how can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, of course a script is executed when it's imported. That's a fact you cannot change except by using a different programming language.

The solution is usually this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That way it's only executed if you run it using `python whatever.py` but not when importing it.

---

To be more detailed on what happens during an import:

If the module is already in `sys.modules`, that entry will be returned. Otherwise the module's code is executed and the globals from that file stored in the `sys.modules` entry. So only the first time you import a module its code is executed.