# Importing one module from different other modules only executes it once. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am confused about some behavior of Python. I always thought importing a module basically meant executing it. (Like they say here: [Does python execute imports on importation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19029079/4362607)) So I created three simple scripts to test something:

main.py

```
import config
print(config.a)

config.a += 1
print(config.a)

import test
print(config.a)
```

config.py

```
def get_a():
    print("get_a is called")
    return 1
a = get_a()
```

test.py

```
import config
print(config.a)
config.a += 1
```

The output when running main.py is:

```
get_a is called
1
2
2
3
```

Now I am confused because I expected `get_a()` to be called twice, once from `main.py` and once from `test.py`. Can someone please explain why it is not? What if I really wanted to import config a second time, like it was in the beginning with `a=1`?

(Fortunately, for my project this behavior is exactly what I wanted, because `get_a()` corresponds to a function, which reads lots of data from a database and of course I only want to read it once, but it should be accessible from multiple modules.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the config module is already loaded so there's no need to 'run' it anymore, just return the loaded instance.

Some standard library modules make use of this, from example [random](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l885). It creates an object of class Random on first import and reuses it when it gets imported again. A comment on the module reads:

```
# Create one instance, seeded from current time, and export its methods
# as module-level functions.  The functions share state across all uses
#(both in the user's code and in the Python libraries), but that's fine
# for most programs and is easier for the casual user than making them
# instantiate their own Random() instance.
```